# Take a peek in my code help me

Tags: java, jsp, switch-statement

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1> This will get the day</h1>


            <b>The Day is:</b>
            <%= request.getParameter("day")%><br>
    <%        

  switch(request.getParameter("day"))
 {
      case 0:
          out.println("It\'s Sunday.");
                  break;
      case 1:
          out.println("It\'s Monday.");
                  break;
      case 2:
          out.println("It\'s Tuesday.");
                  break;
      case 3:
          out.println("It\'s Wednesday.");
                  break;
      case 4:
          out.println("It\'s Thursday.");
                  break;
      case 5:
          out.println("It\'s Friday.");
                  break;
      case 6:
          out.println("It\'s Saturday.");
                  break;            
  }
 %>
```

i'm new to programming please help, i need to get the day when its entered like 1 then its monday if the user entered 3 output will be wednesday Thanks guys!

Comment: So what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Your code is correct man whats wrong explain error or what you exactly need?

Answer (score -1):

You are passing String(`request.getParameter("day")`) in switch case instead of `int`. Try this code.

```
String dayStr = request.getParameter("day");
if (dayStr != null && !"".equals(dayStr)) {
    int day = 0;
    try {
        day = Integer.parseInt(dayStr);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        // Invalid day and handle exception accordingly.
        nfe.printStackTrace();
        day = -1;
    }

    switch(day) {
        case 0:
            out.println("It\'s Sunday.");
            break;
        // similarly other cases
        default:
            out.println("Invalid day.");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: > We can use a String object in the expression of a switch statement **In the JDK 7 release**  [SEE-HERE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html)

Comment: Yes, you are right @AbhijitKumbhar, for that you will need to declare cases like `case "0":` instead of `case 0:`